# how to make effects on button in ios.On clicking on that button it should expand

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift3, swift5

I want to apply effects on button.If click on that button,It should increase in size and other should remain in their original size.In the below image if clicked on jardine,it should expands.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what you have already tried? You could just animate the constraints.

Comment: This is far too broad for Stack Overflow. You need to just start working on it. Get to the point where you have everything working *without* the button expanding, and then try adjusting constraints or maybe using `CGAffineTransformScale`. If you run into problems, come back and ask specific questions.

Comment: I don't know how to do that,that's why I asked @DennisJackman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to animate and transform the button.
It is run perfectly as you aspect

```
func changeButtons(selectedButton:UIButton)
{
    firstBtn.backgroundColor = .white
    firstBtn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    animateButton(button: firstBtn, transformBy: .identity)

    secondBtn.backgroundColor = .white
    secondBtn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    animateButton(button: secondBtn, transformBy: .identity)

    thirdBtn.backgroundColor = .white
    thirdBtn.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
    animateButton(button: thirdBtn, transformBy: .identity)

    selectedButton.backgroundColor = .black
    selectedButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    animateButton(button: selectedButton, transformBy: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2))
}
func animateButton(button : UIButton,transformBy:CGAffineTransform)
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        button.transform = transformBy
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
@IBAction func btnFirstPress(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    changeButtons(selectedButton: firstBtn)
}
@IBAction func btnSecondPress(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    changeButtons(selectedButton: secondBtn)
}
@IBAction func btnThirdPress(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    changeButtons(selectedButton: thirdBtn)
}
```

[image]